# Where to place a non-model database fetch architecturally?

Tags: backbone.js

I am developing a rich client application using Backbone.js and have encountered a situation where I need to fetch 3 values from three database tables and display them.

The rub, however, is that they are not part of my models and I have no need to synchronize them.  They are for display purposes only.  Should I created a child view which adds them to the DOM as part of the render() method?   I'd prefer not to just hack some jQuery code together -but- it doesn't seem to fit nicely into my mental picture of Backbone models and views either.

Comment: Is the 3 values related? Are they statistics? Are they shown on all pages?

Comment: @EmileBergeron They are related.  They are all spot prices for some natural resources.  And, they are all shown on the same page.

Comment: @Notamachine So what is wrong with having a model to hold those related values?

Comment: I am not a Backbone guru so I am open to suggestions.  In my mind it seems a waste of overhead but I'll give it a go and see how it turns out.

Comment: @EmileBergeron Your advice turned out to be good.  I created a model with the values and used one fetch() call to retrieve all three values. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah that's the way to go ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule of thumb in MVCs like Backbone is that the data structure should always be stored in the model layer imo. In your case this could either mean **extending your current models with those ui state related attributes (recommended)** or create a new model and pass it to the views as an option:

```
var myModel = new MyModel();
var newModel = new NewModel();

var myView = new View({
  model: myModel,
  newModel: newModel
});
```

later in the view you can access to the newModel as `this.options.newModel`

Comment: Backbone is not MVC

Comment: @TJ I agree and disagree with this statement :)

Comment: @foo  The three data values live in three different database tables and, if I squint my eyes, I could imagine them as a model - very loosely coupled albeit.  Is there any reason not to display them via a view without using a model?     I am building a multi-tab wizard and these data values are more informational than anything.